# SyntaxError: missing : after property id in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm getting a Javascript error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
function Rolevalidation(){
    if($("#form_role").validate()) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Tax/TaxStorageNew',
            data: $('#form_role').serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                // alert(result);
                if(result > 0) {
                    $('#RoleModal').hide();
                    var id=result;
                    $('.roleId').append($('<option>', {
                        value: id,
                        text: $('#storage_code').val(),
                        text: $('#storage_location').val(),
                        text: $('#supId').val(),
                        text: $('#Reference').val(),
                        text: $('#storage_used').val(),
                        text: $('#pwd/hint').val(),
                        text: $('#access').val()
                    }));

                    jsoptStorage += '<option value="'+id+'">'+$('#storage_code').val()+'</option>';
                    //alert (jsoptrole);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

In this code, I'm trying to pass this data to my Controller named `Tax`, I have made a function `TaxStorageNew` in my controller but this function cannot call.

Comment: `Console.log(result)`

Comment: @uzaif Can't you read the first line of the question?

Comment: `text: $('#pwd/hint').val()`, is not a valid ID, it's probably throwing it off.

Comment: @Farkie, thnx for the answer ! but have tried to change ID('#pwd/hint' )to ('#pwd_hint') ! still its not working !

Comment: And the line number is it not showing after the error message ?